# Why does using a destructuring assignment on a fetch response cause the .json() method to disappear?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I ran into some behavior that was unexpected and that I cannot figure out while working in an aws lambda.

I'm executing a fetch, then doing some different things based on whether it succeeded or failed, and eventually wanting to use the fetch.json() method if everything is kosher. I'm using await to make the interior of my lambda handler "synchronous."

Everything was fine when I assigned the result of the fetch to a variable and then inspected it. But I like tidy code, so I decided to use destructuring assignment, and suddenly things started breaking.

To demonstrate what I'm confused about, I've included a code snippet that duplicates the issue and shows five different things - the first two work, the rest break.

In the third example, "r" is an empty object. The rest operator breaks it, which I do not understand. Is it making a new object and refusing to copy properties over? Do the properties not exist at the time that the destructuring happens? If so, why would ok and status destructure properly?

Four is just a simplified example of three's problem.

Five is also confusing me, because I was able to get the json method, but then it throws an illegal invocation exception when I try to execute it.

Snippet included below:

```js
const one = async () => {
  const r = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  console.log(await r.json());
}

const two = async () => {
  const r = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  const { ok } = r;
  console.log(await r.json());
  console.log(ok);
}

const three = async () => {
  const { ok, status, ...r } = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  try {
    console.log(await r.json());
  } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
     console.log(ok);
     console.log(status);
     console.log(r);
  }
}

const four = async () => {
  const { ...r } = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  console.log(r);
}

const five = async () => {
  const { json } = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  try {
    console.log(await json());
   } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(json);
   }
}

[one, two, three, four, five].forEach(f => f());
```

Thanks again for your time.

Note: For some reason SO is logging the exceptions as empty objects, so here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ygbm6kwq/4/

Edit: Accidentally left out a line in example two, snippet and fiddle updated.

Comment: `I'm using await to make the interior of my lambda handler "synchronous."`   await does not make code synchronous.  `[one, two, three, four, five].forEach`  here you are looping through 5 promises, not the results of 5 promises.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I'm using a spread operator.

Comment: @Keith That's why I put "synchronous" in quotes. I know it's not actually synchronous. I was trying to handwave stuff that's not relevant to the issue. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: (When the snippet console doesn't show the information accurately, you can suggest that question viewers to look in their actual browser console instead - it work just as well despite the snippet running on the other domain)

Comment: Notice that in your first example if you run `r instanceof Response` you will get `true`. That won't be the case if you use the spread operator. Because the spread operator is the equivalent of doing this: `Object.assign({}, r)`. And that empty object that it's in the first argument of `Object.assign` is not an instance of `Response`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The rest operator breaks it, which I do not understand. Is it making a new object and refusing to copy properties over?

Yes, exactly that. The property rest element creates a new object and copies any left-over enumerable *own* properties into it. But the new `r` will be a plain object, not a *[`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) instance*, and as such it does not inherit a `.json()` method.

> I was able to get the json method, but then it throws an illegal invocation exception when I try to execute it.

Yes, it's a *method*. And as such it must be invoked on the instance, with a proper `this` value. You can technically do

```
const response = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
const { json } = response;
console.log(await json.call(response));
```

or even without destructuring, `Response.prototype.json.call(response)`, but there's no point in that.

Comment: 99% of the way there. Is json not an enumerable property because it's part of the Response prototype chain?

Comment: @JSager The problem wasn't with enumerability (tbh I have no idea whether they are enumerable, I just guessed they were not), but that `.json` is an *inherited* property.

Comment: ok thanks. I have a bit of reading to do there, but that clarifies the mystery. I knew I was almost there but the last step of "why" was eluding me. This is why I never write classes :)